# Wrong display data in child component? Angular

Tags: angular

All code demonstration and behavior is here:

There is no need to explain much here.

Look at the stackblitz, open the first row (click on the row). You will see the details of that row. Click on the second row, the detail from the first row will be override with those details from the second row.

Example video here ( what is problem ) :

https://vimeo.com/543841393

Example of code:

HTML code is here:

EXAMPLE WHAT NO WORK:

```
  <ng-container ">
    <div class="d-flex row my-1"> 
        class="w-50"></app-child>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Why ?

Because   public getSingleDispatch(book: any) is http request with new data. This code is only basic example what is problem.
Just imagine i got new data with getSingleDispatch function.

Also example what no work property in my situation:

```
  public test(test: any) {
    return test;
  }
```

what i say doesn't work doesn't work in my code where i do http request. It would work here in stackblitz demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think single detail object only works if you want to show only one detail at time, if you want to show multiples details, you should save multiples data of that details.
with httpRequest to get Details

```
// Inject httpClient or your service to make request. 

public getSingleDispatch(book: any) {
// to avoid to load same detail multimples time, if you already has details saved,
// you only make request if you dont load details previusly.

if( !this.singleDetailsDispatchMap[book.driver]) 
// make request , subscribe and access to response
    this.httpClient.get('http://myApi.test/'+book.driver)
     .subscribe(response => {
     this.singleDetailsDispatchMap[book.driver]=response;
})
  }


// html checking to book expanded and book details 
<ng-container *ngIf="book.expanded && !!singleDetailsDispatchMap[book?.driver]">
        <div class="d-flex row my-1">
          <app-child *ngIf="!!singleDetailsDispatchMap[book?.driver]" 
              [dispatchDetails]="singleDetailsDispatchMap[book?.driver]"
              [closedDetail]="detail"
            class="w-50"></app-child>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
```

I assumed that in the response comes the detail data that interests you given a book, in this case use as an example that given a driver, the details are obtained.

```
 this.httpClient.get('http://myApi.test/'+book.driver)
     .subscribe(response => {
     this.singleDetailsDispatchMap[book.driver]=response;
})
```

After subscribing, the response is saved in the map, using the driver as key, and the details as value,with this structure:

```
this.singleDetailsDispatchMap = {
"driver1": details1,
"driver2": details2
}
```

where the values would be what you want to handle in your api.
that generates a check in the template and when evaluating

```
* ngIf = "book.expanded && !! singleDetailsDispatchMap [book? .driver]"
```

It will be expanded and with values on the map, then it will show the details

Comment: book.singleDetailsDispatch don't exist friend..  singleDetailsDispatch is variable

Comment: yes, but in your function to get detail of book I suggets modification as example , attach that property to book, also I suggest other approach using map to save details

Comment: Check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/expande-table-error-7gh8mp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: this won't work ...... How to explain getSingleDispatch i got NEW DATA HTTP GET REQUEST ? this is no work

Comment: I added an example I think should help you to understand how to load details from request.

Comment: So when I open the first row. I see the details. When the second row again, I see the same details as the first row

Comment: WORK! finally. Please, but please give me a very detailed explanation of what you did here, line by line. vote up for anwear

Comment: I´ll try to explain you as well as possible.  What approach you has been used?? please shared with me a stackblitz code to see how it is and explain you the solution.

Comment: just write in here in comment.

Comment: using map to store details ?

Comment: Friend just tell me what is example with       this.singleDetailsDispatchMap[book.bookingId] = response; and all code

Answer (score 1):

When you make this assignment

```js
  public getSingleDispatch(book: any) {
    this.singleDetailsDispatch = book;
  }
```

you're assigning all child inputs with the selected book.

You can pass the `book` from the `ngFor` to your child component (`dispatchDetails`) directly instead:

```html
  <app-child *ngIf="singleDetailsDispatch" [dispatchDetails]="book" [closedDetail]="detail"
            class="w-50"></app-child>
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expande-table-error-369zyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html)

Comment: I wrote above. I can't pass the book to function, because the book doesn't have all the information. When I do getByID I only get all the information. That's the difference.i take the clicked id, so based on the id i make getById and that http gives me all the information.

Comment: i don;t know how to explain......but i cant prop book to child component. I can't i got new data with more details from http get reqeust..... This is only example what .. i can't create stackblitz with http request from my server...

Comment: @Segma ah I see. That's also fairly simple though. Assuming your `getSingleDispatch` returns an observable, all you need to do is `[dispatchDetails]="getSingleDispatch(book) | async"`